# Microsoft Chart, bar graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I'm trying to make a bar graph, which have to show a bar graph of quality of some goods. My question is about how to make it happen. I'm not sure that the chart control can handle the criterias I want done. 
If you imagine that you have a default product, and you want the quality of the barcode. The quality is describe from A(highest) to F(lowest). The output on the graph should be as followed.

http://billedeupload.dk/upload/files/2011-11/f4e132dd.jpg

The understanding of the graph is that it's showing you the quality of the barcode in as a whole, and individually as for example the quality "A". You can see how good the quality of "A" are, compared to the whole.
Can you do this i visual studio c#? And how?

Im using a winform! ;)

Edited:
I want to make it as a Stacked Bargraph. <-- answer to my own question.
Anybody who have a code example for newbies to coding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The project is old, but I think the source code will help.

WpfSimpleChart
http://wpfsimplechart.codeplex.com/

You should refine your question yet, whether you want to do wpf or winforms.

**EDIT**

After refining the question, here is a cool charting lib for winforms.

ZedGraph

A flexible charting library for .NET
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting back into MSChart, so I'll share my findings in hopes that it helps you (*and you will check my answer as the correct answer*)

I am using LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) to learn MSChart. It is the fastest tool to write C# and render images. I was using Visual Studio, but it takes too much time to build the solution so I can see the results of my changes. I am 'hacking' at MSChart, so I needed faster responses.

I was following the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx to create my LINQPad C# program.

I hope this helps. You could just take my `createChart` function and drop it in your WinForms project. Take a look at the `drawIt` method, that is what brings together the stream into an actual graphic.

FYI,
I am using `SysDraw` = `System.Drawing`

```
SysDraw.Color blueStart = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(124,195,215);
SysDraw.Color blueEnd = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(74,166,192);

SysDraw.Color grayStart = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(153,153,153);
SysDraw.Color grayEnd = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(208,210,211);

SysDraw.Color orangeStart = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(252,165,107);
SysDraw.Color orangeEnd = SysDraw.Color.FromArgb(255,104,4);

void Main()
{
    //chart1 is from Microsoft's sample site
    // other charts are using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx 
    Chart chart1 = createChart1();
    Chart chart2=   createChart2(42, "Chart 2");
    Chart chart3 = createChart2(99, "Chart 3");
    Chart chart4 = createChart2(11, "Chart 4");

    drawIt(chart2, chart2.Name);
    drawIt(chart3, chart3.Name);
    drawIt(chart4, chart4.Name);
    drawIt(chart1, chart1.Name);
}

private void drawIt(Chart drawChart, string name)
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    drawChart.SaveImage(ms,SysDraw.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    SysDraw.Bitmap outImage = new SysDraw.Bitmap(ms);
    outImage.Dump(name);
}
private void drawIt(string imageFilePath)
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    SysDraw.Bitmap outImage = new SysDraw.Bitmap(imageFilePath);
    outImage.Dump(imageFilePath);
}

private Chart createChart2(double dataPointYvalue, string chartName)
{
    string chartAreaName ="Area 1";

    // Chart
    // --------------------------------
    Chart results = new Chart();
    results.Name = chartName;
    results.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
    results.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.None;
    SysDraw.Size size1 = new SysDraw.Size(480,30);
    results.Size = size1;

    // ChartAreas collection
    // --------------------------------
    ChartArea area1 =new ChartArea(chartAreaName);
    area1.Area3DStyle.Enable3D=false;
    //area1.Area3DStyle.Enable3D=true;
    area1.Area3DStyle.WallWidth=10;
    //area1.Area3DStyle.Inclination=10;
    //area1.Area3DStyle.Perspective = 10;
    area1.Area3DStyle.Rotation=1;

    //area1.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;

    area1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
    area1.BackColor = grayStart;
    area1.BackSecondaryColor = grayEnd;


    //      Axes under Area collection
    Axis axisX = new Axis();
    axisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
    axisX.Title ="x axis";
    axisX.IsMarginVisible=false;
    axisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;



    Axis axisY = new Axis();
    axisY.Title = "y axis";
    axisY.IsMarginVisible=true;
    axisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

    area1.AxisX = axisX;
    area1.AxisY = axisY;
    results.ChartAreas.Add(area1);

    // Series Collection Editor
    // --------------------------------
    Series series1 = new Series("Series 1");
    series1.ChartArea = chartAreaName;
    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
    series1.CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder";
    series1.Name = "BarChart";

    series1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
    series1.Color=blueStart;
    series1.BackSecondaryColor = blueEnd;

//  series1.BorderDashStyle= ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
//  series1.BorderColor = SysDraw.Color.Red;

    //series1.Points.AddY(42);
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.Name="MyPoint";
    dp.YValues= new double[]{dataPointYvalue};
    series1.Points.Add(dp);
    results.Series.Add(series1);

    // Legend
    // --------------------------------
//  Legend legend = new Legend("Chart 2 Legend");
//  legend.DockedToChartArea = "Chart 2 Area 1";
//  legend.Docking = Docking.Right;
//  legend.IsDockedInsideChartArea = true;

//  results.Legends.Add(legend);

//  series1.Legend = "Chart 2 Legend"; //You can assign each series to a different legend.

    // Title
    // --------------------------------
    Title title = new Title(string.Format("Your whatever is {0}",dp.YValues[0]));
    title.Docking = Docking.Right;
    title.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
    //title.DockedToChartArea = chartAreaName;
    //results.Titles.Add(title);

    // Annotations
    // --------------------------------
    ArrowAnnotation arrowAnnt = new ArrowAnnotation();
    arrowAnnt.AnchorDataPoint=dp;
    arrowAnnt.Height=-5;
    arrowAnnt.Width=0;
    arrowAnnt.AnchorOffsetY=-2.5;
    arrowAnnt.SmartLabelStyle.IsOverlappedHidden = false;

    TextAnnotation textAnnt = new TextAnnotation();
    textAnnt.AnchorDataPoint = dp;
    textAnnt.AnchorOffsetX = -10;
    textAnnt.ForeColor=SysDraw.Color.White;
    textAnnt.Text = dp.YValues[0].ToString();

    //results.Annotations.Add(arrowAnnt);
    results.Annotations.Add(textAnnt);
    return results;
}
private Chart createChart1()
        {

            Title title1 = new Title();
            ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
            Legend legend1 = new Legend();

            Series series1 = new Series();
            DataPoint dataPoint1 = new DataPoint(0, 6);
            DataPoint dataPoint2 = new DataPoint(0, 9);
            DataPoint dataPoint3 = new DataPoint(0, 5);
            DataPoint dataPoint4 = new DataPoint(0, 7.5);
            DataPoint dataPoint5 = new DataPoint(0, 5.6999998092651367);
            DataPoint dataPoint6 = new DataPoint(0, 7);
            DataPoint dataPoint7 = new DataPoint(0, 8.5);
            Series series2 = new Series();
            DataPoint dataPoint8 = new DataPoint(0, 6);
            DataPoint dataPoint9 = new DataPoint(0, 9);
            DataPoint dataPoint10 = new DataPoint(0, 2);
            DataPoint dataPoint11 = new DataPoint(0, 7);
            DataPoint dataPoint12 = new DataPoint(0, 3);
            DataPoint dataPoint13 = new DataPoint(0, 5);
            DataPoint dataPoint14 = new DataPoint(0, 8);
            Series series3 = new Series();
            DataPoint dataPoint15 = new DataPoint(0, 4);
            DataPoint dataPoint16 = new DataPoint(0, 2);
            DataPoint dataPoint17 = new DataPoint(0, 1);
            DataPoint dataPoint18 = new DataPoint(0, 3);
            DataPoint dataPoint19 = new DataPoint(0, 2);
            DataPoint dataPoint20 = new DataPoint(0, 3);
            DataPoint dataPoint21 = new DataPoint(0, 5);
            Chart results = new Chart();
            //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(results)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // resulting chart
            // 
            results.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            results.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
            results.BackSecondaryColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            results.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
            results.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            results.BorderlineWidth = 2;
            results.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 15;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.IsClustered = false;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.IsRightAngleAxes = false;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = 0;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Rotation = 10;
            chartArea1.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 0;
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            chartArea1.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            chartArea1.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            chartArea1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            chartArea1.BackSecondaryColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            chartArea1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            chartArea1.Name = "Default";
            chartArea1.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            results.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            results.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            legend1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            legend1.Enabled = false;
            legend1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            legend1.IsTextAutoFit = false;
            legend1.Name = "Default";
            results.Legends.Add(legend1);
            results.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 53);
            results.Name = "chart1";
            series1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
            series1.ChartArea = "Default";
            series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(220)))), ((int)(((byte)(65)))), ((int)(((byte)(140)))), ((int)(((byte)(240)))));
            series1.Legend = "Default";
            series1.Name = "Default";
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint2);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint3);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint4);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint5);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint6);
//          series1.Points.Add(dataPoint7);
//          series2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
//          series2.ChartArea = "Default";
//          series2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(220)))), ((int)(((byte)(252)))), ((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(65)))));
//          series2.Legend = "Default";
//          series2.Name = "Series2";
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint8);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint9);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint10);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint11);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint12);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint13);
//          series2.Points.Add(dataPoint14);
//          series3.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
//          series3.ChartArea = "Default";
//          series3.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(220)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(10)))));
//          series3.Legend = "Default";
//          series3.Name = "Series3";
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint15);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint16);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint17);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint18);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint19);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint20);
//          series3.Points.Add(dataPoint21);
            results.Series.Add(series1);
//          results.Series.Add(series2);
//          results.Series.Add(series3);
            results.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(412, 296);
            results.TabIndex = 1;
            title1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            title1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
            title1.Name = "Title1";
            title1.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(32)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            title1.ShadowOffset = 3;
            title1.Text = "3D Cylinder";
            results.Titles.Add(title1);


            SysDraw.Size mySize = new SysDraw.Size(480, 170);
            results.Size = mySize;

            return results;
        }
```